# Determine whether $f(x,y) = |y|^{\alpha}$ satisfies the Lipchitz condition.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Where $\alpha \in [0,1),y \in [-1,1]$

It seems to be satisfied, if I choose $\alpha = 1/2,y = 1/2,z = 1/3$

But I can't think how to begin

$$||z|^\alpha-|y|^\alpha| \leq \text{???}$$

Could I have a push?

Comment: Try with $y=0$.

Comment: Ahh I get the result $|z|^{\alpha} \geq |z| $, nice one.

Comment: Close. You get the result (contradiction) $|z|^\alpha \ge L |z|$ for the (assumed) Lipschitz constant $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative blows up at $0$, so the Lipschitz condition cannot hold near $0$.  Consider the graph of $y=x^{1/2} = \sqrt x$.  It's the upper half of the parabola $y^2 = x$, which obviously has the $y$-axis as a tangent line.  So $y=\sqrt{|x|}$ has a vertical tangent at $0$.